# when i submit the form all the values which i entered gone out

Tags: php, javascript

The values which i have entered gone out if i submit the form with any validation error. I want remaining values has to be stay in particular field except the validation error filed

Comment: show the validation code, please

Comment: What have you tried?  Please edit your post to include code, plus specific errors/issues you have encountered while trying to implement this.

Comment: If the validation is in your PHP code, executed when the form is submitted from the browser, then you'll need to get the entered values from the request (which you are presumably already doing if you're validating them) and return them back to the browser within the form HTML.

Comment: Are the downvotes for the beginner question, or for the non-native english speaker? Even without code it seemed pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you varify this in Javascript? If yes, just add the following to your form header and replace `VarifyForm` with your own function name. If the form is `return true;` in your function and if it isn't valid `return false;`

```
onSubmit="return VarifyForm();"
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're validating you can save the submitted data in a `$_SESSION` variable. When you redraw the form you can populate the fields with it.